# MariaDB opposite of limit

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;
```

The above statement outputs the newest 3 entries but I want the oldest 3 without using ASC instead of DESC, like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC BOTTOM 3;
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3?

Comment: Why "without using ASC"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the data that you want from the table by ascending order, and then query that subquery to reorder the data:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 3
) result
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Alternatively, you can also query the data in ascending order, and then programmatically reverse the order of the array, with something like [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).